# deleting \x00 in front of a number in list

Tags: python

I have a list as follows,how to delete the junk '\x00\x00.. in front of 563015

```
['\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00563015', '553261', '541526']
```

Comment: how was this list generated?

Comment: +1 to @MattDMo, but expanding on it in case it isn't obvious to the OP: When you have a question of the form "I parsed/fetched/whatever this data wrong, now how do I fix it?" the best answer is usually "show us how you parsed it and we'll show you how to do it right so this problem doesn't come up". In other words, this is usually a form of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a list of strings, `strip` is used to remove characters from either end of a string.

```
a = [ #... ]
b = [s.strip('\x00') for s in a]
```

You can substitute `lstrip` for `strip` if you only care about the characters on the left.